# How to parse a string in a calculator in R?

Tags: r, string

I wrote a calculator program in which the User enters two numbers and an arithmetic operation between the numbers, then presses Enter and gets the result, or rather did a string parsing, but it doesn't work. What can this be related to? I also wrote the code so that I could exit the function

```
  add<- function(x,y){
      return(x+y)
    }
      subtract <- function(x,y){
      return(x-y)
    }
      multiply <- function(x, y) {
         return(x * y)
    }
      div <- function(x,y){
        if(y==0){
          return("Error")
          break
    }
      else if(y!=0){
        return(x%/%y)
      }
      
    }
    
   
      res<-NA
       repeat{
    print("9", quote=FALSE)
    user_string <-
      readline(prompt = ("Enter: "))
    
    if(user_string== 9){
      break # to stop the programme
    }
    
    components_of_user_string <-
      unlist(strsplit(user_string, split = '')) #splitting the line

      num1<-as.numeric(components_of_user_string[1]) #first number
      num2<-as.numeric(components_of_user_string[3]) # second number


    us_chosen_operation <-
      components_of_user_string[2]
    operations_vector <-
      c('+', '-', '*', '/') 
    choice <- match(us_chosen_operation, operations_vector)
    operator <- switch(choice, ' + ', ' - ', ' * ', ' / ')
    
    result <-
      switch(
        choice,
        add(num1, num2),
        subtract(num1, num2),
        multiply(num1, num2),
        divide(num1, num2)
      )
    print(paste(num1, operator, num2, "=", result))
}
```

Comment: variable `result` is not defined before the line `is.numeric(result)`. Also,  there is a stray `{` before the line `res<-NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String parsing with `eval(parse(...))` could be an option :

```
repeat {
  input <- readline(prompt = ("Enter: "))
  print(eval(parse(text = input))) 
}

# Enter: (-4)+2
# [1] -2
# Enter: raise_to_degree(2,3)
# [1] 8
```

Comment: But if I want, for example, to add up the numbers (-4)+2, then he can't count, right? I also wanted the user to set the numbers and the operation themselves

Comment: Not sure to get your first point : `eval(parse(text = "(-4)+2"))` also works.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. But I asked about how to make it so that when I run my code, a line comes out( I did this) and there the user can enter: 4+(-2) and get just the answer (-2)

Comment: see my edit : is it what you're looking for?

Comment: It's really good method, but i don't understand how correctly use it in my cod. This method ignoring all my functions

Comment: How do you mean 'ignoring all my functions': your own function `raise_to_degree` is working in example above.

Comment: In my code, above were functions for addition,subtraction, multiplication and division, so I want, your method operate with this functions. I'm trying to do it, but I can't achieve the desired result

Comment: where do you define `num1`, `num2` and  `c_of_user_string` in your code? Please provide a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can see, I added changes to the code above

Comment: The code above works with all the functions you defined : I gave `raise_to_degree` as an example, but all others (`multiply`, ...) work. Not sure to understand where the problem is..

Comment: Yeah, I understood. Thank you!