# Passing symbolic expression as argument of function in R

Tags: r

Rookie question but I can't find anywhere the answer.
I need an input for example `x^3-9*x`

For example, I'm writing an interactive application where the user is prompted to input a symbolic expression for a function:

```r
f=readline(prompt="A symbolic / mathematical function:")
```

then, the input from the console could be: `x^3-9*x`

I need to make the program understand that `f` is a function not just characters.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66928067/13513328) helps

Comment: The latter, I want them to input something through the console like x^3-9*x , so that the user doesn't have to manually write the function after what you just wrote.

Comment: That's not necessarily a beginner or basic topic in R. Can they only use "x" as the variable? Other variables? This can become tricky for you in a hurry

Comment: The user will know to only input "x" as variable and no other, also the functions will be no more complicated than the mentioned.

Comment: You could take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string But be careful, I don't recommend using `eval(parse(...))`. Bad things can happen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a wrapper around `readline()` that captures the string input and then creates a function. Here is an example using `rlang`. The single argument `x` is hard coded in, but this could be made to be more advanced.

```r
readline_fn_x <- function(prompt) {
  
  fn_str <- readline(prompt = prompt)
  rlang::new_function(rlang::pairlist2(x = ), rlang::parse_expr(fn_str))
  
}
```

This will return a function. Here it is evaluated at `f(2)`

```r
> f <- readline_fn_x(prompt="A function pls:")
A function pls:x^3-9*x
> f(2)
[1] -10
```